# I am unable to connect to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to connect to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com through "apns-sharp" class library, but all I get is the following error message: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connect
ed host has failed to respond 17.172.238.209:2195"

Why Is That?

Comment: It sounds like the domain your trying to use no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your provider may not allow to go out using port 2195.